# Is it possible to get the Size of a WidgetSpan in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For calling `.layout()` on a `TextPainter` object it is necessary to call `.setPlaceholderDimensions` before, if the `TextSpan` has for example a `WidgetSpan` as child.

Since I want to measure elements on my screen and I have `WidgetSpan`'s, I need to set the dimensions, otherwise the following error would occur:

```
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart': Failed assertion: line 102 pos 12: 'dimensions != null': is not true.
```

My question is, is it possible to get the `Size` of the `WidgetSpan` before calling the `layout()` method?

The partial code of the code currently looks like this:

```
final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: textSpan,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
);

final List<PlaceholderDimensions> placeholderDimensions = [];

if (textSpan.children == null) return [];
for (InlineSpan inlineSpan in textSpan.children!) {
    if (inlineSpan is WidgetSpan) {
        placeholderDimensions.add(PlaceholderDimensions(
            // TODO: add correct dimensions for InlineSpans
            size: Size.zero,
            alignment: inlineSpan.alignment,
        ));
    }
}

textPainter.setPlaceholderDimensions(placeholderDimensions);

textPainter.layout(maxWidth: double.infinity);
```